# gulp-watch-sass not working with current code

Tags: sass, gulp

I am using the https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch-sass plugin. My code is currently the following:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    watchSass = require("gulp-watch-sass"),
    minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')({ lazy: true });


gulp.task("sass:watch", function () {
    gulp.watch('./src/scss/**/*.scss', gulp.series('sass'))
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css/'))
});
```

What I want is to be making edits to my sass files and then that gets compiled to my folder for the CSS in this command, But it's not working?? in terms of the CSS file is not being updated with the changes.

Paths to each folder are:

```
/Users/xxxxx/project/src/scss (Sass)

/Users/xxxxx/prroject/public/css (CSS folder)
```

Comment: is the target destination /Users/xxxxx/ **prroject** /public/css is correct ? just check

Comment: that is correct...